# mysql select into outfile text file tab seperated with line breaks

Tags: mysql, select, tabs, into-outfile

ive been trying to find someone with similar problem but without luck so im opening a new questions.

I have a simple select statement that generates a text file.

```
SELECT '1','2'
UNION all
SELECT Column1, Column2
INTO OUTFILE '/path/file.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n\r' **<-- THE ISSUE**
FROM db.table limit 0,100;
```

The output is fine except one thing. It keeps adding \N to line break. I dont want any character to be the line break i want the line break to be a actual line break.

As it is now:

```
1  2
Example   Example\N
Example   Example\N
```

How i want it to be

```
1  2
Example  Example
Example  Example
```

Ive tried so many combinations, even if i skip the entire LINES TERMINATED BY '', it still adds \N to the output file. If i use the workbench export button, it works excellent, but this is a part of a stored procedure so that is not a solution for me.

It is expecting a BIN_NUM, HEX_NUM or TEXT_STRING.

How can i apply a HEX_NUM to the statement? The mysql version is 5.6

Thanks in advance

Comment: Saw that i used , instead of TAB. Now fixed, question is correct now.

Comment: `\n\r` is a quite unusual way to end a line. Common choices are `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n`.

Comment: ive tried all of them but i keep getting the value \N for line break, i just want the actual line break not a char for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the `\N` was filled in when the field was null. I just simply added a `IFNULL(Column,'')` to the columns initial select and now my problem is gone!

Comment: you saved my life with this answer.